# How to check date format on SQL Server

Tags: sql

trying to check date format for all the values in my table and return a 1 if correct or 0 if false, here is my code so far, any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
(Case when new_originationdate is not NULL
    AND new_originationdate not like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]'
        then 1 else 0 end) as CIEDIT_SYN_41,
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the code you have tried. Did it solve your issue? If not, what is the problem?

Comment: No it didn't, when I query  "Select * from #ci_run_comparison4 where CIEDIT_SYN_41 = '1'" it just lists all the dates in the database, if it works correctly, it should show 0 records because all the dates are in the correct format

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this approach is that it will treat "2017-13-32" as a valid date.  It's not.

You didn't specify that platform you are running on.  You can probably use a date/time function provided by your DB platform (see [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) for SQL Server) to cast the string to an actual DateTime value.  If the cast succeeds, the string is a valid date.

Comment: Ended up using a substring test to test date formats.                                                      (Case when new_originationdate is not NULL
  AND (substring(new_originationdate,5,1) = '-'
   and substring(new_originationdate,8,1) = '-'          . . . .

Comment: Thanks for the link though, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

```
DBCC useroptions
```

Syntax
The syntax goes like this:

DBCC USEROPTIONS
[ WITH NO_INFOMSGS ]
The optional NO_INFOMSGS argument suppresses all informational messages that have severity levels from 0 through 10.

Example
Here’s an example of running the command, and the results I get on my current test machine:

DBCC USEROPTIONS;
Result:

```
+-------------------------+----------------+
| Set Option              | Value          |
|-------------------------+----------------|
| textsize                | -1             |
| language                | us_english     |
| dateformat              | mdy            |
| datefirst               | 7              |
| lock_timeout            | 5000           |
| quoted_identifier       | SET            |
| arithabort              | SET            |
| ansi_null_dflt_on       | SET            |
| ansi_warnings           | SET            |
| ansi_padding            | SET            |
| ansi_nulls              | SET            |
| concat_null_yields_null | SET            |
| isolation level         | read committed |
```